# Анализ CSV файла БЕЗ библиотек

Tags: python, csv, анализ

Ранее я задавал вопрос, связанный с программой , обрабатывающей CSV файл, на который уже ответил господин @MaxU. Проблема в том, что данное задание необходимо решить без библиотек ,максимум встроенная - csv.
Самое задание:Нужно считать csv файл(скрин ниже(1 столбик - номер, 2- название, 3-время отбытия, 4-время в пути)) в словарь(Важно!), и уже работать над словарем. Пользователь вводит название маршрута(2 столбик), программа должна вывести всю информацию о введённом маршруте, отсортированную по времени в пути.
(спасите, я могу решить это с Pandas, легко, но без - не представляю как.)
Вот код с Pandas:

```
import pandas  

put= input('введите рейс: ') 

a = (pandas.read_csv('train.csv', encoding='cp1251', header=None,index_col=0, sep=';',
                     names=['Номер','Рейс','Время отбытия','Время в пути'],
                     parse_dates=['Рейс']))
        .query("Рейс == @put")
        .sort_values('Время в пути')

if not a.empty: 
    print(a)
else:
    print('Нету информации')
```

Как задачу решить используя, максимум - csv
Тестовый файл(train.csv):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Представьте что вам необходимо:

1. Создать подходящую структуру к Вашим [данным](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python).
2. Написать функцию для выборки подходящих данных и необходимый [компаратор](http://www.cyberforum.ru/python/thread2047084.html) к ним.
3. [Реализовать](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/stroki-funkcii-i-metody-strok.html) либо использовать разрешенный условиями заданий [парсер](https://habr.com/post/239081/).
4. Спарсить CSV в созданную структуру и применять к результату описанную во втором пункте функцию.